# MIN() with ignoring empty records in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table, My_Values, which could have some missing records; by "missing", I mean the content of the record = ''.

I want to get the minimum value of a number of rows with the same name, but the problem is, if I use this:

```
SELECT MIN(my_value) FROM My_Values WHERE name LIKE 'John'
```

It returns `''`. (a blank string?  term?)

I know MIN() is supposed to ignore NULLs but it appears not to ignore ''.  What's the best way to write the query to tell it to ignore '' as well?

Comment: How about  SELECT MIN(my_value) FROM My_Values WHERE name LIKE 'John' AND my_value != ''      ?

Comment: what type is 'my_value'?

Comment: @Michael That's it.  I actually tried something like that but must have made a mistake and so thought there was something more complex I was overlooking.  Should you just move your comment to an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky my_value is a string representation of a duration of time (e.g. "0:00:02:173000")

Comment: is your hours number zero-padded?  If not, you may have sorting issues and, therefore, min() may not always return a correct value.  Consider  that "9:00:02:173000" is greater than "10:00:02:173000"

Comment: @DmitryBeransky It's not.  (Thanks for that catch).  It's the str representation of a Python timedelta.  I could zero pad the string, but this will require chasing down other uses of this format in the program--is there a way for SQLite to see the string as a timedelta?  MIN(TIME(my_value) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the extra condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT MIN(my_value) FROM My_Values WHERE name LIKE 'John' AND my_value != ''
```